# Confusion about PowerBI Query Editor View Tab

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I am going through the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-ui) and I am a bit confused about the View Tab of the Query Editor.

In the tutorial it's presented as a panel where I would be able to select "Data View" and "Schema View" like here:
[image]

When I installed the Power BI Desktop (I tried both 32 and 64 bit versions from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58494)).
I see following items in the View Tab:

[image]

I am a bit perplexed whether I am using the same product described in the tutorial since I don't see the expected "Data view" and "Schema view" options.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial is basing snippets from the Power BI Service, as opposed to Power BI Desktop. Power BI Desktop is the downloadable software that you will use on your local machine. That being said, Power BI Service does allow users to develop reports in the Service. Development in the cloud (Power BI Service) will be very similar to development in Power BI Desktop (the local software), but there are some slight differences. Overall, I believe, Power BI Desktop has more functionality than Power BI Service when it comes to report development.

This may sound confusing, but really its pretty typical of Microsoft's app offerings. Think of Excel and Word, both of which have local software you can download and use. But they also have the minimalized functionality that exists in the cloud.

And to answer your question specifically, no, it appears that Power BI Desktop does not have those views at this time.